# 301 Redirect from dynamic ASPX

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a daunting problem with dynamic redirects that I have to do on WordPress website that was before an aspx website.

I am looking for advice for a week now and tried almost everything with different outcomes but none proved successful.

I need to redirect complex URLs such as:

```
/Products/tabid/174/CategoryID/134/List/0/Level/a/ProductID/6572/Language/en-GB/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName%2CProductName
```

to something simple like

```
http://domain.com/folder/
```

I've used number of ideas including loads from StackOverflow but none seem to tackle this specific example. Using standard Redirect 301 rule will work for as long as I don't have ? in the link. I understand this is beyond the scope of Redirect 301 and I need to use RewriteRule.

I tried this (got this from the excel spreadsheet for dynamic urls redirection):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SortField=ProductName%2CProductName$
RewriteRule ^Products/tabid/174/CategoryID/134/List/0/Level/a/ProductID/6572/Language/en-GB/Default\.aspx$ http://domain.com/folder/? [R=301,L]
```

But still on entering the url it yields 404 page.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
## BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

## messing up
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SortField=ProductName%2CProductName$
RewriteRule ^Products/tabid/174/CategoryID/134/List/0/Level/a/ProductID/6572/Language/en-GB/Default\.aspx$ http://domain.com/folder/? [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Do I place it correctly? Is the code right? I would appreciate any ideas and clues.
Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the mastery. The code was good just the placing was incorrect. After dozen tries and errors I found the correct formula. I had to amend placing of my redirect rule. Here is how it looks:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Products/tabid/174/CategoryID/134/List/0/Level/a/ProductID/6572/Language/en-GB/Default\.aspx$ http://doamin.com/folder/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SortField=ProductName%2CProductName$Products/tabid/174/CategoryID/134/List/0/Level/a/ProductID/6572/Language/en-GB/Default.aspx?SortField=ProductName%2CProductName
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```